# python - How to calculate time complexity of while loop

Tags: python, time-complexity

I studying TSP these days.
I understood complexity of TSP algorithm with DP solution.
But I wonder if I can calculate time complexity of those code below (getting actual path of shortest time)
I don't know how to calculate the time complexity of while loop when I don't know when it will exactly ends.

```py
def get_path(cache, w, n, dist, start=0):
    cur_loc = start
    visited = 1
    path = [start]
    while len(path) < n:
        for k in range(n):
            if visited & (1 << k):
                continue
            if dist - w[cur_loc][k] == cache[k][visited | (1 << k)]:
                path.append(k)
                dist -= w[cur_loc][k]
                cur_loc = k
                visited |= 1 << k

    path.append(start)
    return path
```

'w' : adjacent matrix with cost
'n' : number of nodes
'cache' : Memoization table from DP, (N row, 2^n col)
'dist' : shortest distance obtained from TSP with DP solution
'start' : literally start node

full code is here

```py
import sys
input = sys.stdin.readline
inf = float('inf')
n = int(input())
w = []

for _ in range(n):
    line = list(map(int, input().split()))
    w.append(line)

start = 0
N = len(w)
VISITED_ALL = (1 << N) - 1
cache = [[None] * (1 << N) for _ in range(N)]

def find_path(last, visited):
    if visited == VISITED_ALL:
        d = w[last][start] or inf
        cache[last][visited] = d
        return d

    if cache[last][visited] is not None:
        return cache[last][visited]

    min_time = inf
    for city in range(N):
        if visited & (1 << city) == 0 and w[last][city] != 0:
            r = find_path(city, visited | (1 << city)) + w[last][city]
            min_time = min(min_time, r)
    cache[last][visited] = min_time
    return min_time


def get_path(cache, w, n, dist, start=0):
    cur_loc = start
    visited = 1
    path = [start]
    while len(path) < n:
        for k in range(n):
            if visited & (1 << k):
                continue
            if dist - w[cur_loc][k] == cache[k][visited | (1 << k)]:
                path.append(k)
                dist -= w[cur_loc][k]
                cur_loc = k
                visited |= 1 << k

    path.append(start)
    return path


d = find_path(start, 1 << start)
p = get_path(cache, w, n, d, start)
print(p)
print(d)
for line in cache:
    print(line)
```

Comment: To calculate the complexity of a while loop, look at the condition it is checking and find the upper and lower bound of that, as well as the average (where possible).

Comment: @LarrytheLlama appreciate it!